# How to deploy a rest web service in WSO2

Tags: rest, service, wso2

I have created rest webservice using java. I would like to deply and publish it in wso2 so that my clients can access it. Please provide me any details on this as the resources provided in the WSO2 web site is vague. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy any web application on [WSO2 Application Server](http://wso2.com/products/application-server/) and Manage the APIs through [WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/api-management/try-it/).